# Electric oven losing power intermittently

Tags: electrical, oven

My electric oven is intermittently losing power. It isn't turned on, it just loses all power as if the circuit were turned off. Then it comes back after a few seconds or as long as a minute.

I'm not sure whether the problem is with the oven or the circuit. My electrical panel and all circuit breakers are only a few years old. The oven is 14 years old.

I don't know why the circuit would just cut off and back on without tripping. But I also don't know why the oven would lose and regain power.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does anything else lose power when the oven does?

Comment: Possibly a lose connection in the cables from the oven to the wall.

Comment: **If** there is a loose connection that is quite dangerous as loose connections can get very hot and start fires.

Comment: I would search for anything out of the ordinary occurring in house electrical. Once I talked to a resident who had to turn an oven on to get half the circuits in the house to work.  The utility lineperson had sent me over there to warn their power would be interrupted to fix a broken-off hot wire (which was the cause of that; the lineperson stumbled upon that while fixing something else).

Comment: How often is the power loss?  What specific symptoms are you getting?  Are we just talking about a clock face going dark?

Comment: If it were a major/loose wiring issue, it would present itself upon baking, not doing nothing. This sounds more to me like the controller path starting to fail. Intermittent problems often are heat-related. I would suspect dry/leaked capacitors in the DC power supply. I would have it checked out sooner than later because a power supply is cheap and easy to replace, but if during the actual failure, it takes out a custom controller board, you're likely better off getting a new oven.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. Nothing else loses power. And yes, it's just the clock face going dark. Only the oven. It happens randomly. Sometimes a few times per day. Sometimes every 2-3 days. My biggest question is whether the problem is electrical or appliance related. I think it sounds more likely to be the appliance from the comments people have shared.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a problem in the oven control panel, oven power supply or an electrical connection. Electrical connection would be potentially dangerous. However, that is probably least likely because ovens typically have a hardwired connection and the wires aren't moved around except if the oven is removed for service.

14 years may not seem like much. But according to a quick Google search, average oven lifetime is 16 years. A control panel problem can be very expensive to repair or replace - and at that age "replace" may not even be an option. I had some oven control panel problems and got a touchpad replacement and general repair from [FixYourBoard.com](https://fixyourboard.com/techzone/ovens/whirlpool_e6_f2_e1_f5/e6_f2_e1_f5.html) - no connection except a satisfied customer. A new electric oven can cost anywhere from $500 to $4,000, or even more, depending on single vs. double oven, self-cleaning, convection and other features, so a major repair may actually pay if you can get a few more years out of the oven.

Key questions:

- Manufacturer/model #
- When power comes back on, does the control panel indicate that there was a power failure? If it does not (assuming it does if you turn the breaker off/on), that would almost certainly point to a control panel problem. If it does indicate a power failure then it could be wiring (unlikely but possible), power supply or control panel.